# Passing file upload name from $_FILES to $_POST for storage in database

Tags: php, database

I'm still fairly new to php but basically what i'm looking to do is to pass the name of the file that's uploaded so that it can be entered into the database with the corresponding form information.

```
// uploading file
if ($_FILES){
print_r($_FILES);
mkdir ($dirname, 0777, true);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$dirname."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}


// Form Processing
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{

    $varName = $_POST['formName'];
    $varLat = $_POST['formLat'];
    $varLong = $_POST['formLong'];
    $varPic = $_FILES["file"]["name"];


        $db = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db($dbname ,$db);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO new_submissions (locationName, latitude, longitude, picture) VALUES (".
                        PrepSQL($varName) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varLat) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varLong) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varPic) . ")";
        mysql_query($sql);

        header("Location: thankyou.html");


        exit();
}
```

Comment: and whats the problem?

Comment: `$varPic=''; if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) { $varPic = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; ..process file here.. }`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Sorry I should have explained more initially. The photo capture is being handled by phonegap/javscript on a mobile device. Then the file is being uploaded using javascript to the php file and the form is being directly posted to the php file. What I've just realized now is that the form is probably finished executing before the file upload has completed and as a result can't get the name.

Answer (score 0):

Put this

```
// uploading file
if ($_FILES){
print_r($_FILES);
mkdir ($dirname, 0777, true);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$dirname."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
```

inside this code like this

```
// Form Processing
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{

   if ($_FILES){
      print_r($_FILES);
      mkdir ($dirname, 0777, true);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$dirname."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
   }

    $varName = $_POST['formName'];
    $varLat = $_POST['formLat'];
    $varLong = $_POST['formLong'];
    $varPic = $_FILES["file"]["name"];


        $db = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db($dbname ,$db);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO new_submissions (locationName, latitude, longitude, picture) VALUES (".
                        PrepSQL($varName) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varLat) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varLong) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($varPic) . ")";
        mysql_query($sql);

        header("Location: thankyou.html");


        exit();
}
```